# hybrid or native mobile app development (phonegap or eclipse)

Tags: java, android, ios, html

I want develop a basic & simple mobile application which want run with native hardware tools like camera and WiFi. but I don't have time to learn Java (need app done in few days) that's why I want use HTML, css, JavaScript skills which I have already good knowledge and FYI I am a php programmer. so what is good suggestion for me where from I can start ?

Comment: Please add what have you tried so far? You have to start somewhere and when you get stuck you post your code here. I suggest you look into XAMARIN http://xamarin.com/

Comment: i want to develop a mobile app as soon as possible it will just simple mobile app which will run as cross-platform. i am not expert in java so i thinking to use HTML5 to develop app. my question is where from i have to start which IDE or language will help me and how? i just heard about phonegap is framework and eclipse is  IDE.
@DamienJoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **phonegap.**

PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about.

http://phonegap.com

Phonegap Doc.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html

How to use phonegap via comandline tools to intall phoengap and plugins.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface